# Can you add value to a Casascius physical coin?

Tags: physical-coins

The firstbits address on the front of the coin (once fully resolved from blockexplorer) is just like any other address right? I can buy a 1 BTC Casascius physical coin, copy the address, bury that coin in my backyard, and use regular transactions to keep increasing its value?

Comment: What you see on the front of the coin is not the Firstbits. It's simply a fixed number of first characters of the address. The only robust way to deduce the full address from what you see is Casascius' records, https://www.casascius.com/fulllist.txt. But yes, once you find the address of the coin, it's a normal address you can add more coins to and access them with the private key within.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add value.  The block chain only knows public keys. It doesn't care how or where the corresponding private keys are stored.